# Help solving $ | x + 2| + 3| x - 1| > 2x - 1$

Tags: inequality

$$ | x + 2| + 3| x - 1| > 2x - 1$$

My idea was to solve $| x - 1|$ and $| x + 2|$ it in two cases (when is positive and when is negative). It didn't work!

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would suggest always sketching the graph first. That will eliminate many algebraic errors.

[image]

There are three cases to consider:

(1) $x< -2$: Then the equation is $-x-2 + 3(1-x) > 2x -1$, or $x < \frac{1}{3}$. Hence all of $(-\infty, -2)$ satisfies the equation.

(2) $-2 \le x < 1$: Then the equation is $x+2 + 3(1-x) > 2x -1$, or $x < \frac{3}{2}$. Hence $[-2,1)$ satisfies the equation (since $\frac{3}{2}>1$).

(3) $x \le 1$: Then the equation is $x+2 + 3(x-1) > 2x -1$, or $x >0$. Hence all of $[1,\infty)$ satisfies the equation.

Hence the solution set is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: thank you! it was very helpful

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Consider $3$ cases:

$$x\le -2$$
$$-2<x\le 1$$
$$1<x$$

Answer (score 0):

With these kind of problems a sketch is very often useful. Split the LHS into separate intervals as each term changes sign. You should find yourself sketching 3 different straight line segments for the LHS and then it is just a matter of seeing whether each segment meets the line $y=2x-1$ and deciding the appropriate intervals for which the inequality is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler way :

1. $|x+2|$ is the distance between $x$ and $-2$.
2. $|x-1|$ is the distance between $x$ and $1$.
3. $|x+2|+3|x-1|$ is minimum when $x$ is between $-2$ and $1$, but due to factor $3$, when $x$ goes closer to $1$, the overall sum will decrease. Hence the minimum is for $x=1$
4. for $x=1$, the minimum is $|x+2|+3|x-1|=3$, hence $|x+2|+3|x+1|\ge3$
5. Hence the inequation is always true for $x\le2$. You just have to verify it for $x\ge 2$, but in this case, you can remove all $|.|$